# XML XSL XSD Validation:

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I am having difficulties referencing all 3.
I have already written my XML,XSD and XSL but it doesn't seem to work with the referencing.
Here is a simple example using the same referencing.

XSD:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
   xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
   elementFormDefault="qualified">

   <xs:element name="email">
     <xs:complexType>
       <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
       </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>

 </xs:schema>
```

XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="email.xsl"?>

 <email
   xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com email.xsd">

   <to>John</to>
 </email>
```

XSL:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="email">
          <h2>To</h2>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="John"/></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So what is the question? I don't see one. What is the problem? Nothing has been described as problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XSLT does not work because your `email` element has a namespace, and to match an element with a namespace using an XPath you always have to explicitely declare a prefix and use it.

You need to write the XSL like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:ws="http://www.w3schools.com"
  version="1.0"> 

  <xsl:template match="/"> 
    <html> 
      <body> 
        <xsl:for-each select="ws:email"> 
          <h2>To</h2> 
          <td><xsl:value-of select="ws:to"/></td> 
        </xsl:for-each> 
      </body> 
    </html> 

  </xsl:template>
```

I am not sure what you are expecting from the XSD: it seems correct, but it won't affect in any way the application of the XSLT.

`email` is the root element in your XML, so you can have only one `email` element per XML file - probably you should have a different root element above it.

Note also that you are generating dubious HTML: a `<td>` that is not inside a table.